# "Comparison between" versus "comparison for"

Tags: differences, prepositions

What's the difference between "comparison between" and "comparison for"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Comparison between" is used when you are listing choices to be compared- as in, "We can make a comparison between Toyotas and Volkswagons."

"Comparison for" is used when articulating the intent of the comparison- as in, "We can compare these two answers for similarities."

So, "what's being compared" vs "what you're looking for during the comparison"